# Running a eVB application on WM6 device

Tags: evb

I have a eVB application that I need to get running on newer WM6+ devices and need to know if at all its possible?

I have installed the VB Runtime files and I can manage to get the program installed but it fails to run with "Access Denied" Errors.

I have the eVB source files so if I need to re-package the installation I can.

Has anyone ever managed this?

Answer (score 0):

I never tryed this before, but you can re-install the runtimes and see if it fixes.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't support eVB on newer devices.

You can convert the program to NS Basic/CE - it will also boost the performance of your program and make it compliant with Windows phone 6.5.